# Duvida bibliotecas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Boa tarde!

Sou novo no desenvolvimento utilizando a linguagem Python, gostaria de algumas dicas de bibliotecas boas para estar estudando e principalmente uma voltada a "manipular sites" (atualmente eu somente conheço o Selenium WebDriver, porem gostaria de conhecer outras), eu sei que é uma pergunta um tanto vaga ou até mesmo retardada, mas para quem está começando agora ajuda muito saber de bibliotecas populares que poderiam estar ajudando no desenvolvimento.

Agradeço a todos pela atenção e compreensão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, Planilha Online voce pode user [Selenium Web Driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) ou ate mesmo o Selenium IDE para [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd) [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) que roda direto no Browser.

Cotacao de dolar, voce pode buscar uma [Webservice](https://any-api.com/) que voce consiga usar com API REST.

Desenvolvimento Web, voce pode usar [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) , é bem rapido para se aprender ele, ou [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), um pouco mais rebuscado pq pode ser feita tanto para Desktop como WEB. Indico buscar Cursos na [Alura](https://www.alura.com.br/), a [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) ou se tiver sem grana [UdemyCourseDownloader](https://udemycoursedownloader.net/)

Comment: @fernandosavio adcionei os links, porem não tenho responsabilidade pelo Udemy Course Downloader e não incentivo a pirataria.

Comment: Me referia mais ao sites dos frameworks mesmo. :D